# Puppeteer not recognizing string

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function test() {
    // adjustment 1:
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: ['--start-maximized', '--no-sandbox']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://cod.tracker.gg/warzone/profile/psn/xRUFFRYDERX/overview')

    await page.waitForSelector('#app > div.trn-wrapper > div.trn-container > div > main > div.content.no-card-margin > div.site-container.trn-grid.trn-grid--vertical.trn-grid--small > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.trn-grid__sidebar-right > div > div');
    const level = await page.$eval('#app > div.trn-wrapper > div.trn-container > div > main > div.content.no-card-margin > div.site-container.trn-grid.trn-grid--vertical.trn-grid--small > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.trn-grid__sidebar-right > div > div > div.highlighted.highlighted--giants > div > div > div.highlight-text')
    console.log(level);
}
test();
```

I am attempting to create a COD tracker remote tool but I keep receiving the error below, i think it's failing to interpret the level variable as a string but I'm not really sure why?
`(node:20216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Expected to get |string| or |function| as the first argument, but got "undefined" instead.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing the whole `pageFunction` of [`page.$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1):

> page.$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])

To retrieve its content you will need to add it as a second argument, like: `el => el.innerText`.

*Note:* I trimmed a bit your long selector, but it will return the same result anyway.

```js
const level = await page.$eval('div.highlight-text', el => el.innerText)
```

Comment: Thank you, i wasn't sure what the argument would be, does puppeteer have somewhere i could see a list of compatible arguments?

Comment: I recommend to study their official docs at https://pptr.dev/. There it is explained what are the mandatory options, arguments of each method. The most important methods are `$`, `$$`, `$eval`, `$$eval`, `evaluate` when it comes to data scraping. After 1-2 examples it will become clear how to use them. I think the biggest takeaway is: you need to evaluate the content of the desired DOM elements with the proper approach, in this: arrow functions will be your help. Good luck!